# How should I get my model's instances to belong to all users in my user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models, has-many-through

I have the following setup and I want to ensure that all brands in my brand model belong to all users in my user model. I would also like to ensure that once a brand has been created, and it belongs to all users, it will also belong to future users that sign up down the line.

**Brand model**

```
has_many :brand_users
has_many :users, :through => :brand_users

after_create :associate_with_all_users

def associate_with_all_users
  User.find(:all).each do |user|
    users << user
  end
  save
end
```

BrandUser model

```
belongs_to :brand
belongs_to :user
```

User model

```
has_many :brand_users
has_many :brands, :through => :brand_users
```

When I try the following in the console, it shows that currently the last brand instance only belongs to a single user and not both (there are currently 2 users that exist).

```
>> User.all.count
=> 2

>>BrandUser.last.user_id
=>1 #Should not belong to just the one user but both
```

Comment: Just to confirm, BrandUser.count == 1?  Also you should be able to do self.users = User.all instead of the loop.

Comment: No, BrandUser.count == 4 (right now, although it will rise to a lot, like 200).

Comment: How many brand's and users do you have at the moment?

Comment: 4 brands and 2 users. Oddly the association gives User.first.brands.count == 3 and User.last.brands.count == 1

Comment: Check my answer below to see if that works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models look correct, you may be able to clean up your Brand association call to:

```
def associate_with_all_users
  self.users = User.all
  # save I don't believe this is necessary anymore if you assign the association
end
```

As for ensuring all newly created users receive all Brand's, you could do a

```
class User
  after_create :associate_with_brands

  def associate_with_brands 
    self.brands = Brand.all
  end
end
```

or maybe look at an http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

Comment: Thanks that after_create hook is what I was looking for. I did realise that the problem isn't with my models but with my controller, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042781/how-can-a-rails-form-be-filtered-to-show-only-objects-without-tags-and-by-a-curr I answered the first part to my own question there but need to filter the (:taggings => { :id => nil } ) to only nil taggings by current user.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, if you try `Brand.first.users` don't you get all of your users?

Either way, if every brand is associated with every user and viceversa, why don't you do try something like this:

```
def User > ActiveRecord::Base

  def brands
    Brand.all
  end

end

def Brand > ActiveRecord::Base

  def users
    User.all
  end

end
```

Comment: Seconded. Why try setting up associations if you know in advance that everything will be associated with everything.

Comment: Will you ever have to remove an associated brand from a user? Will they be able to customize their brands after create?

Comment: Thanks. I suppose too many cooks (opinions) in the kitchen lead me to it. Krisitan, no to answer your question.